# Codename one Icon and picture size on build

Tags: codenameone, mobile-application

I build an app, and each device skin will show a different size of pics that I attached in button. How can I choose the size of the pics that fit with every skin phone type, please?

Here is ip6 skin type
https://ibb.co/3FWQsw3
https://ibb.co/ZW34Pbh

Here is ip8 skin type
https://ibb.co/THQpJ97
https://ibb.co/5jvy5mz

Thank you

Comment: There are several different approaches to get the images at the wanted size. If the images are included with the sources, you can use multi-images: https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---fetch-an-image-from-the-resource-file---add-a-multiimage.html The Codename One CSS has a good support for multi-images. Instead, if the images are downloaded at run time, you can scale them on the server-side (Cloudinary?) or you can scale them in the app-side using APIs like `Image.scaled(CN.convertToPixels(sizeInMM), -1)`. You can adapt the size of the Components to the screen using the Codename One Layouts.

Comment: In the free section of the Codename One Academy ("Java For Mobile Devices"), you can find lessons about the basics of the development with Codename One, in which multi-images and device densities are explained.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at it.